# AngularJS Pass String into Frontend Function From ng-repeat List

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, list

I have a project with hundreds to thousands of books and I am using a Java Rest back-end to query the DB (using bootstrap too):

- I have an initial list of books with a unique ID that I need to list. Data that gets initially listed are the Books Title and date published (ID is used to generate the lists hrefs only).
- When an book is clicked it calls a function to grab that books extra data to display.
- Inside of the clicked book I have another function that repeats all the above data into two tabs (Tab one for the book showings and tab two for the comments).

**MY ISSUE:**
Is when I try to pass the book ID into the function calls it attempts to iterate through my ENTIRE book list (500k + books) and doesn't call that specific ID which I believe is due to angular NOT writing out the HTML correctly and refreshes the list.bookId

I tried *ng-click="getExtraBookInfo({{list.bookId}})"* which creates:

*ng-click="getExtraBookInfo(34234234-34234234)"*

but doesn't pass in correctly because the backend is expecting this format:

*ng-click="getExtraBookInfo('34234234-34234234')"*

so in order to do so I needed to do this on the frontend:

*ng-click="getExtraBookInfo('{{list.bookId}}')"*

This works ok on the above function call but the repeater list never writes out the html further down in the tabs.

When I debug the code it is literally passing *{{list.bookId}}* as the Id even on the getExtraBookInfo() call!

NOTE: In my services.js I am using http.get with the bookId appended to the URL.

**Overall Code:**

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="list in bookList" ng-controller="BookListController">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading_{{list.bookId}}">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel_{{list.bookId}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panel_{{list.bookId}}" ng-click="getExtraBookInfo({{list.bookId}})">
          {{list.bookTitle}} - {{list.bookDate}}
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel_{{list.bookId}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading_{{list.bookId}}">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#showings_{{list.bookId}}" aria-controls="showings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Showings</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#comments_{{list.bookId}}" aria-controls="comments" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="showings_{{list.bookId}}">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <th>Showing</th>
                  <th>Location</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat="book in getBookDataById({{list.bookId}})">
                    <td>{{book.showingName}}</td>
                    <td>{{book.showingLocation}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-click evaluates the expression in the context of your scope, so `{{ }}` interpolation will not achieve the expected results. Try omitting the handlebars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do like this, No need to use expression while passing as a parameter

```
ng-click="getExtraBookInfo(list.bookId)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue(s). First Like William B and Sajeetharan said I didn't need the {{}} but also I found my SQL was passing EVERYTHiNG on null. This lead me to find that my rest service wasn't getting the bookId from the get url because I was not correctly implementing the @PathParam.

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-pathparam-example/

Thanks everyone!